# wpf - can't use custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom control inside a StackPanel

```
<Window x:Class="Video_Editor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Video_Editor">
<Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Margin="10,40,10,10" Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" >
            <m:CustomControl Name="testControl"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The custom control currently doesn't do anything.

```
public class CustomControl: ItemsControl
{
}
```

I tried to do this in the window's constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    testControl.Items.Add("item");
}
```

I am getting an error "the name "testControl does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You should really use databinding instead of code behind.

Comment: By the way, what does you custom control do?

Comment: @HighCore this is just an example.  If this statement doesn't work here, it won't work where I need it.

Comment: my point is that you don't normally subclass WPF controls unless you have a good reason to. And again, you should really use databinding. How is the  `m` namespace declared? post the full XAML.

Comment: I just updated the question with full xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `x:Name` since you are deriving from another `FrameworkElement` that is exposing the `Name` property itself.

If a `FrameworkElement` has set its `Name` property (which `ItemsControl` seems to be doing) you cannot declare the `Name` property on the derived type, but you can use the `Xaml` `x:Name` property so you can decare a `Name` and access from code behind

Example:

```
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" >
        <m:CustomControl x:Name="testControl"/>
    </StackPanel>
```